# Confusion regarding the use of logical quantifiers and rigorously expressing mathematical statements in general

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I am trying to get better at writing math ideas rigorously and symbolically. Consider the proposition: *"The sum of two odd integers is an even integer."*

Formally (I think), this can be expressed as: (1) "For all integers $x$ and $y$ such that $x=2k+1$ and $y=2q+1$ where $k$ and $q$ are integers, $x+y=2r$ where $r$ is an integer."

Would it be more formal to write: (2) "For all integers $x$ and $y$, if there exist integers $k$ and $q$ such that $x=2k+1$ and $y=2q+1$, then $x+y=2r$ where $r$ is an integer."?

Does statement(1) have the same logical structure as statement(2); that is, is there an implicit "if...then..." in statement(1)?

Is the following symbolic expression correct?
$$\forall x,y\in\mathbb{Z}: (\exists k,q\in\mathbb{Z}: x=2k+1 \land y=2q+1 \implies \exists r\in\mathbb{Z}: x+y=2r)$$

**Every time I introduce a new variable, do I need a logical quantifier?

**In general, given proposition $P$, is  $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{Z}: P(x)$ logically equivalent to $x,y\in\mathbb{Z} \implies P(x)$? If so, it seems that a statement in Predicate Logic has been replaced with a statement using Propositional Logic and a notion of sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every time I introduce a new variable, do I need a logical quantifier?

Yes, absolutely. Sometimes universal quantifiers are suppressed (that is, we write down a formula with some free variables but think in terms of that formula's **universal closure**) but in my opinion this is bad practice especially when first learning formal logic.

> In general, given proposition $P$, is  $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{Z}: P(x)$ logically equivalent to $x,y\in\mathbb{Z} \implies P(x)$?

Not really, since the latter hasn't introduced $x$ and $y$ via a quantifier. The former is a sentence, the latter merely a formula; the former is however (modulo some mild rewriting) the universal closure of the latter.

> If so, it seems that a statement in Predicate Logic has been replaced with a statement using Propositional Logic and a notion of sets?

Implicitly taking universal closures does let us strip away an "outermost" universal quantifier. However, it doesn't get rid of all quantifiers in general. Consider for example the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity, which has the form $$\forall \epsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\exists \delta\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\forall x\in\mathbb{R}[\mbox{stuff}].$$ We can "elide" the "$\forall\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$" by looking instead at a formula whose universal closure is that sentence, but we can't similarly erase the remaining quantifiers. So very little "propositionalization" is actually possible.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much simpler to put it as follows:$$(\forall m,n\in\Bbb Z)(\exists r\in\Bbb Z):(2m+1)+(2n+1)=2r.$$There is no need to introduce all those other symbols. But, yes, what you wrote is correct, except that instead of $2r+1$ you should simply have $2r$.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced $2r+1$ with $2r$ in the question.